# Issue with running application TIBCO BWCE

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I got this error when I run my application in **TIBCO BWCE**, this is the first time it appears.
I'm pretty sure I have all my schemas and wsdl files in the application and I checked all the namespaces too.

> 2023-10-12T15:34:00,028 ERROR [pool-17-thread-1]
> c.t.b.thor.runtime.model.Constituent - **TIBCO-BW-CORE-500102**: Failed to
> install BW Module [my-app:1.0.0.qualifier], DeploymentUnit
> [my-app.application:1.0].    
> com.tibco.bx.core.faults.BxException: BX-600025: Create module failed
> for module [my-app] version [1.0.0.qualifier] application
> [my-app.application 1.0].    
> com.tibco.bx.core.faults.BxException: BX-600028: Adding definition
> failed for process [com.package.myProcess].    
> com.tibco.bw.core.runtime.schemaresolver.SchemaResolveException:
> **TIBCO-BW-SCHEMA-RESOLVER-500104**: Failed to resolve Schema [namespace=,
> location=null], due to exception
> [com.tibco.bw.cache.runtime.CacheException].    
> com.tibco.bw.cache.runtime.CacheException: **TIBCO-BW-CACHE-500030**: The
> location [null] is external to the BW Module
> [initial@reference:file:../../../../../../../../../../repository/my-app/my-app/]
> and it is ignored.  Intra-BW module location is required because
> multiple documents share the targetNamespace [].

When I run the application on another desktop it works without problems. So I tried several things, like changing my workspace and reinstalling TIBCO Studio, but unfortunately I had the same problem.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me resolve this issue.
And have a good day everyone

Comment: Hi, Do you get the problem in a runtime environment ? or in Studio debugger ?
In Studio you may try the following:
. Create a new workspace / import your application / do a clean
. Do a refactor
. Check you have access to all the directories used by your applications
. Check if there is disk space available on your machine (for the different disks you may have)
. Disable the anti-virus
. Re-install Studio

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelM Thank you for your response. I found the cause of the problem. In my application I use some shared modules and in one we declare the schema twice, but unfortunately Tibco didn't specify the schema name or path.